# Java socket client if unconnected

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

I have an android app in Java for a socket client.
I want the app to continue the normal workflow if the socket isn´t connected but it only does it after like 10 seconds of trying the connection and it goes again trying to connect to the socket. What can I do to be faster or just to exit the "trying" code?

This is the code

```
// connection
      String host = "192.168.16.60";
      int port = 12345;

      try {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);

        if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
          final DataOutputStream ToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          ToServer.write(1);
```

Comment: Your socket code runs in a thread. So your app meanwhile can do what it wants to do.

Comment: Either run the socket connection in a Thread, or lower the Socket timeout delay

Comment: BTW I highly recommend you use Web(Server)Sockets vs (Server)Sockets. It will save you many many headaches

Comment: There is a `connect()` overload with a timeout parameter. NB `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testng it. An exception would have been thrown. Don't write pointless code.

Comment: How long do you want it to wait?

Comment: Yes, I might be using threads to do it, it looks the right way to do it.